# Updating HTML Page Title By Passing Angular JS Directive Value in JavaScript script tag

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to update the page title dynamically by creating a pageTitle directive and passing it in the `<script>` tag.

I know I can do which works

```
<head>
<title page-title></title>
</head>
```

but I am trying to do `<script type="text/javascript">document.title='{{page-title}}'</script>`

It shows me 0 as Title

Comment: Do you really have a variable named 'page-title'? You can't use {{}} in a script tag as that is only for HTML. Also your script tag most likely lives outside the scope of your angularJs application. Instead inside your controller use $window.document.title to set the title of your document.